# Google address autocomplete api in Stenciljs

Tags: google-api, stenciljs

I am trying to add a search field for an address using google's address autocomplete in a Stenciljs component. There aren't any resources on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you'll need to load the google maps api script, so that you can interact with the global `google.maps` object. You can either do that by including a script tag, or write something like the following helper function.

```js
const googleApiKey = '...';

export const importMapsApi = async () =>
    new Promise<typeof google.maps>((resolve, reject) => {
        if ('google' in window) {
            return resolve(google.maps);
        }

        const script = document.createElement('script');

        script.onload = () => resolve(google.maps);
        script.onerror = reject;
        script.src = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${googleApiKey}&libraries=places`;

        document.body.appendChild(script);
    });
```

In order to get the TypeScript types for the global `google` object, you should install `@types/googlemaps` into your dev-dependencies.

Then you'll need to implement a function that allows you to search for places, e. g.:

```js
export const searchForPlaces = async (input: string, sessionToken: google.maps.places.AutocompleteSessionToken) => {
    const maps = await importMapsApi();

    const service = new maps.places.AutocompleteService();

    return new Promise<google.maps.places.AutocompletePrediction[]>((resolve) =>
        service.getPlacePredictions({ input, sessionToken }, (predictions, status) => {
            if (status !== maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                return resolve([]);
            }

            resolve(predictions);
        }),
    );
};
```

None of this is specific to Stencil btw. All that is left to do is to use the `searchForPlaces` function in your component. A very simple example would be something like:

```js
@Component({ tag: 'maps-place-search' })
export class MapsPlaceSearch {
    sessionToken: string;

    @State()
    predictions: google.maps.places.AutocompletePrediction[];

    async componentWillLoad() {
        const maps = await importMapsApi();
        this.sessionToken = new maps.places.AutoCompleteSessionToken();
    }

    async search = (e: InputEvent) => {
        const searchTerm = e.target.value;

        if (!searchTerm) {
            this.predictions = [];
            return;
        }

        this.predictions = await searchForPlaces(searchTerm, this.sessionToken);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <input onInput={this.search} />
                <ul>
                    {this.predictions.map(prediction => <li key={prediction.description}>{prediction.description}</li>)}
                </ul>
            <Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

The place search will give you a `placeId` for each prediction. That and the session token you can pass on to a `maps.places.PlacesService` to get the details for the place and auto-fill your form or whatever you're trying to achieve.